# Android Getting Sound Levels

Tags: android, audio, record, audio-recording

I'm a newbie in programming and I wanna build a sound recording application.
I have this code which is recording sound and puts a time-stamp :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{ 
private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
    private static String mFileName = null;

    private RecordButton mRecordButton = null;
    private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;

    private PlayButton   mPlayButton = null;
    private MediaPlayer   mPlayer = null;

    private void onRecord(boolean start) {
     if (start) {
            startRecording();            
        } else {
            stopRecording();
        }
    }

    private void onPlay(boolean start) {
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
        }
    }

    private void startPlaying() {
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        mPlayer.release();
        mPlayer = null;
    }

    private void startRecording() {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        try {
            mRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
        }

        mRecorder.start();
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }

    class RecordButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartRecording = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onRecord(mStartRecording);
                if (mStartRecording) {
                    setText("Stop recording");
                } else {
                    setText("Start recording");
                }
                mStartRecording = !mStartRecording;
            }
        };

        public RecordButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start recording");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    class PlayButton extends Button {
        boolean mStartPlaying = true;

        OnClickListener clicker = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(mStartPlaying);
                if (mStartPlaying) {
                    setText("Stop playing");
                } else {
                    setText("Start playing");
                }
                mStartPlaying = !mStartPlaying;
            }
        };

        public PlayButton(Context ctx) {
            super(ctx);
            setText("Start playing");
            setOnClickListener(clicker);
        }
    }

    public MainActivity() {

     theDate date = new theDate();
     String sDate = date.curDate();
     String sTime = date.curTime();
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/TSP_Recordings/Date_"+sDate+"_Time_"+sTime+".3gp";
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        mRecordButton = new RecordButton(this);
        ll.addView(mRecordButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

                0));
        mPlayButton = new PlayButton(this);
        ll.addView(mPlayButton,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                0));
        setContentView(ll);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mRecorder != null) {
            mRecorder.release();
            mRecorder = null;
        }

        if (mPlayer != null) {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
    }    
}


package com.tsop.tsp_recorder;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class theDate {
static Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

public static String curDate() {
     int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
String sDate = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" 
+ month
+ "-" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
return sDate;
     }

    public static String curTime() {
     String sTime = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) 
+ "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "-"
+ c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
return sTime;
     }

     public static long duration() {
     long dur = c.getTimeInMillis();
     return dur;
    }
}
```

I need to change it and make it messure the sound levels.
I'll use the `getMaxAmplitude` method,but this method returns only the last result,before it was called.

I think I should use a loop,but the `start` method is capturing and encoding continuously.
How can I get the current amplitude,for example in a period of 1 second,on my recording?

Thanks

Comment: I believe getMaximumAmplitude() is the standard way -- call it repeatedly and update your UI. If you want to do something mor soffisticated, you'll have to read the raw data and do something like this: http://blog.bjornroche.com/2013/07/peak-meters-dbfs-and-headroom.html

Comment: Ok,I'll try this and if I have any questions,I'll ask you again,thank you